# Cannot open database "SportStore" requested by the login. The login failed

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have a typical tutorials application on ASP.Net MVC - sportstore, and of course i use database connection using Entity Framework code first mechanism. Everything worked fine, then I moved to another themes of tutorial and forgot about this app. Now I had to come back and suddenly there is an error:

> Cannot open database "SportStore" requested by the login. The login failed.

Why does this error appears I don't know because the login is right. For creating my database i used windows authentication. My connection string in `web.config` file is:

```
<add name="EFdbcontext" 
     connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=SportStore; Integrated Security=false;" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Help me please or just give me the right way for looking tutorials where this trouble is described

These are errors details below

[image]

[my error in Visual Studio 2015](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2NQc.png)

Comment: [C# Connection Strings](http://www.connectionstrings.com) look for sql server database connection strings and how to configure in your .config file

Comment: Sorry for my english, can you explain what to do please

Comment: add integrated security = true

Comment: i am sorry but nothing changed

Comment: I changed Integrated security to true and nothing is changed.

Answer (score 3):

- `Integrated Security = False` : User ID and Password are specified in the connection.
- `Integrated Security = true` : the current Windows account credentials are used for authentication.
- `Integrated Security = SSPI` : this is equivalant to true.

Comment: Is that instance running ? can you connect to "(localdb)\v11.0" from sql server managemend studio for example ?

Comment: i have not sql server management studio, instead i can see that my database exist in SQL Server Object Explorer, but i can not see my tables, there is error occurs: Login is failed and so on as i wrote earlier.

Comment: If you can connect the instance from server explorer then this is not a connection string problem.

anyway try to check if instance is running. open some cmd and run 
"C:\>sqllocaldb info v11.0"
is its state running ? if yes after you set "Integrated Security = true" your connection string is ok.